# copy file using spring integration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration

how would you copy a file from one place to another using spring integration. in my case i want to copy a file outside the war to inside the war. here is the code snippet i am thinking about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-1.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-1.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-1.0.xsd
             ">

<poller max-messages-per-poll="1" id="defaultPoller" default="true">
    <interval-trigger interval="1000"/>
</poller>


<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"    
                              filename-pattern="ha-jdbc-cluster1.xml"
                              directory="file:/etc/****/" />


<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="classpath:/WEB-INF/classes" />
```

but shamefully it does not work. does anyone know how to do it?

thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is with target directory. You're using "classpath:" prefix which can't be used to write files to, only to read from.

Please let us know what you're trying to achieve by copying file for this path and we will try to come up with another approach to do same.

Comment: hi yasha thanks for your post, what i am trying to do here is get the config file from outside the war to inside the war, so that the users can config it outside, but when the app starts, the config would be pulled inside the war and the app would work according to that. please let me know if i need to explain anything else, thanks for your co-operation, i love this forum, mostly nice guys.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work. Classloader will not see updated file after application started. I'd suggest keeping configuration file on different location and configure your app/web server's classpath to load it.

Answer (score 0):

the directory on the file:inbound-file-adapter should be something that can resolves to a single directory (a java.io.File instance). There's no support for reading from multiple directories with one adapter, last I checked...

I'd try changing the directory on the inbound and the directory on the outbound to something sane / well known like two directories in /tmp - /tmp/a and /tmp/b. if that works, then you know your configuration is sane, just the values for the directories are wonky. If youre using Maven and either STS / Eclipse or IntelliJ, its easy to bring up the inbound channel adapter implementation class and debug (FileReadingMessageSource, IIRC) to what it's doing.